# how can I convert date(YYYY, MM, DD) format to YYYY/MM/DD with python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a JSON that returns a date in the following date format:

```
datetime(2015, 12, 1)
```

So the key value from JSON is

```
'CreateDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
```

In order to be able to subtract two dates, I need to convert above to date format:

```
YYYY/MM/DD
```

so in above case that would become: 2015/12/01

Is there a smart way to do that? Is it at all possible? Or do I really have to parse it as a block of text? I tried using datetime.strptime, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You can subtract them independently of the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime module has a function for doing this which is pretty easy as shown below

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime(2015,12,1).strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Also read more about the module here https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

```
datetime(2015,12,1).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

will do the trick for you. A complete python program would look like this.

```
# import the datetime and date classes from the datetime module   
 from datetime import datetime, date 

# create your datetime(..) instance from your JSON somehow
# The included Python JSON tools do not usually know about date-times, 
# so this may require a special step

# Assume you have a datetime now
dt = datetime(2015,12,1)
# Print it out in your format
print( dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") )
```

Two important details:

1. You are using just a date in a Python datetime. Nothing wrong with that but just note that the Python datetime module also has a `date` class
2. You can enable your JSON encoder/decoder to recognise dates and datetimes automatically but it requires extra work.

Now, to subtract datetimes from each other they should remain as instances of the `datetime` class. You can not subtract datetimes from each other once they have been formatted as a string.

Once you subtract a Python `datetime` from an other `datetime` the result will be an instance of the `timedelta` class.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# time_diff here is a timedelta type
time_diff = datetime(2015,12,1) - datetime(2014,11,1)
```

Now you can look up the Python timedelta type and extract the days, hours, minutes etc. that you need. Be aware that timedeltas can be a negative if you subtract a later datetime from an earlier one.